# Vertical and horizontal lines draw differently despite the same values in landscape mode

Tags: line, draw, sprite-kit

I need to draw a grid with horizontal and vertical lines in Sprite Kit. When in portrait mode everything works as expected. I don't know why but when in landscape mode the space between vertical lines are bigger than that of between horizontal lines. Besides that, vertical lines are thicker than the horizontal ones. Here's what I do to draw two lines, one piece of horizontal and vertical each:

```
CGMutablePathRef path= CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 100.0, 0.0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 100.0, 300.0);

SKShapeNode *line = [SKShapeNode node];
line.path = path;
line.strokeColor=[SKColor greenColor];
[self addChild:line];

CGMutablePathRef path2= CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path2, NULL, 0.0, 100.0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path2, NULL, 300.0, 100.0);

SKShapeNode *line2 = [SKShapeNode node];
line2.path = path2;
line2.strokeColor=[SKColor blueColor];
[self addChild:line2];
```

Here's what I get in portrait mode:[image: Here's what I get in portrait mode]

And Here's the one I get in landscape mode:[image: And Here's the one I get in landscape mode]

As you can see, in the portrait mode, there's a square in the lower left corner, which means horizontal and vertical lines are the same distance away from the origin. But in the landscape mode, this is not the case and you can see a rectangle in the lower left corner.

I have not been able to test it on the real device yet.

Comment: Did you try to play with scene's `fillMode`?

Comment: Actually no. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to change your scene.scaleMode to use SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill.

```
   SKSceneScaleModeFill,
   SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill,
   SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit,
   SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill
```

Comment: Setting the scene scaleMode to SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill solved the problem.